# .Net 6 Web Api accept x-www-urlencoded

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, x-www-form-urlencoded

I was trying to read the form url encoded body in ASP.net WebAPI (.Net 6). But I always gets null value from it, Am I doing it wrong ?

Here my endpoint code

```
public class TestObj
{
  [FromForm(Name = "empId")]
  public string? EmpId { get; set; }

  [FromForm(Name = "firstName")]
  public string? FirstName { get; set; }

  [FromForm(Name = "lastName")]
  public string? LastName { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost("Test")]
public string Test([FromForm] TestObj formData)
{
  string? emp = formData.EmpId ?? "EmpId NULL";
  string? fName = formData.FirstName ?? "FirstName NULL";
  string? lName = formData.LastName ?? "LastName NULL";

  return $"Hello World {emp} - {fName} - {lName}";
}
```

and here is my request

```
POST /MyController/v1/Test HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.2
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 89601ac3-bd53-4ec0-84db-5aebe7b5f007
Host: localhost:7177
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 40
 
empId=xxx&firstName=fName&lastName=lName
 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 19 Jul 2022 03:41:09 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 
Hello World EmpId NULL - FirstName NULL - LastName NULL
```

Comment: I just tested this and I can't reproduce your issue. [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0R5Pw.png) and [Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdOJ4.png)

Comment: Please provide full instructions on how to reproduce this. As I've shown above, I'm unable to.

Comment: In an attempt to reproduce it I followed these steps: 1) Select to create new ASP.NET Core Web API project. 2) Select .NET 6.0 (Long-term support). 3) Click create. 4) In the Controllers folder, add a new empty MVC Controller called TestController. 5) Add the code provided above (except changing the URL to `/Test` rather than `Test`). 6) Start the project. For me it runs on https://localhost:7039. 7) Post to https://localhost:7039/Test 8) Get response `Hello World xxx - John - Smith`. -- This worked flawlessly. So please figure out what's different and include it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for this the problem occurred because of my middleware.